# elif statement SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Could somebody kindly let me know why is there a `SyntaxError`? I use macOS Mojave and have installed `IDLE` version 3.7.1.

```
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice.')

    elif age < 12:
        print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')

        elif age > 2000:
            print('Unlike you, Alice is not undead, immortal vampire.')

            elif age > 100:
            print('You are not Alice, grannie.')
```

Comment: correct the formatting

Comment: Back you should go to the official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comment: @GauthamM His question directly pertains to the incorrect formatting - editing it would make the question useless.

Comment: @connectyourcharger Actually that was what I meant and not the formatting of the question.

Comment: @GauthamM Yes, but changing the code format to be correct would not inform the user of his mistake. He/she should follow the answers posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is wrong:

```
name = input('whats your name? ')
age = int(input('whats your age? '))
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice.')
elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
elif age > 2000:
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
    print('You are not Alice, grannie.')
```

Comment: Thank you Joe Iddon for the help. But the SyntaxError is still there. This time in line 3 of the code. More specifically the colon is being highlighted in red.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I missed a bracket on line 2. Please try again with the updated version...

Comment: It works now Joe. Just started learning how to code. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

'elif' should have the same indent as the 'if'

remove white space before your elif

```
if test expression:
    Body of if
elif test expression:
    Body of elif
else:
    Body of else
```